Primordials is not defined - not gulp - when running angular
I've got a node setup containing the following node_modules:
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/common": "18.2.6",
  "@angular/compiler": "18.2.6",
  "@angular/core": "18.2.6",
  "@angular/forms": "18.2.6",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "18.2.6",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "18.2.6",
  "@angular/router": "18.2.6",
  "graceful-fs": "^4.2.11",
  "ngx-toastr": "^17.0.2",
  "rxjs": "7.8.1",
  "tslib": "2.7.0",
  "zone.js": "~0.14.10"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "18.2.6",
  "@angular/cli": "18.2.6",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "18.2.6",
  "@types/body-parser": "^1.19.5",
  "@types/express": "^5.0.0",
  "express": "^4.21.0",
  "nodemon": "^3.0.1",
  "typescript": "^5.5.0"
}

running node v20.17.0
I'm trying to run the command 'ng serve' but I keep getting the error:

fs.js:44
primordials;
    ^

ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
at fs.js:44:5
at req_ (C:\Users\thoma\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\natives\index.js:143:24)
at Object.req [as require] (C:\Users\thoma\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\natives\index.js:55:10)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\thoma\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\yam\node_modules\graceful-fs\fs.js:1:37)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1469:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1548:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1288:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1104:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1311:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)


I've tried upgrading and downgrading the angular, node and specifically the graceful-fs module as per other posts instructions. I see that a lot of people had this problem with gulp and a long time ago but I don't have that installed?

What is the graceful-fs dependency for? How is a filesystem library going to work with Angular? Is that a dev dependency?

Also, you could message this guy and see if they remember what they meant by "due to a npm module unzip": https://github.com/isaacs/node-graceful-fs/issues/234

I’m pretty sure it’s part of angular cli? It seems to be part of the angular/cli module cause of part of the error code. I didn’t have it in dependencies before but put it there to force a different version which was a posted solution to a similar problem. ( obviously it didn’t work for this one )
